# Why is Selection Sort so fast in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, computer-science

I'm studying for a technical interview right now, and writing quick javascript implementations of different sorts.  The random-array benchmark results for most of the elementary sorts makes sense but the selection sort is freakishly fast.  And I don't know why.

Here is my implementation of the Selection Sort:

```
Array.prototype.selectionSort = function () {
  for (var target = 0; target < this.length - 1; target++) {
    var min = target;
    for (var j = target + 1; j < this.length - 1; j++) {
      if (this[min] > this[j]) {
        min = j;
      }
    }
    if (min !== target) {
      this.swap(min, target);
    }
  }
}
```

Here are the results of the same randomly generated array with 10000 elements:
BubbleSort => 148ms
InsertionSort => 94ms
SelectionSort => 91ms
MergeSort => 45ms

All the sorts are using the same swap method.  So why is Selection Sort faster?  My only guess is that Javascript is really fast at array traversal but slow at value mutation, since SelectionSort uses the least in value mutation, it's faster.

** For Reference **
Here is my Bubble Sort implementation

```
Array.prototype.bubbleSort = function () {
  for (var i = this.length - 1; i > 1; i--) {
    var swapped = false;
    for (var j = 0; j < i; j++) {
      if (this[j + 1] < this[j]) {
        this.swap(j, j+1);
        swapped = true;
      }
    }
    if ( ! swapped ) {
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the swap Implementation

```
Array.prototype.swap = function (index1, index2) {
  var val1 = this[index1],
      val2 = this[index2];
  this[index1] = val2;
  this[index2] = val1;
};
```

Comment: You could find out if your implementation is correct: check if the resulting array is sorted.

Comment: Well you should be able to validate your results easily enough by traversing the array just once, checking if the next number is greater than the previous (or vice versa for descending).

Comment: yes the result is correct. I'm just not sure if my implementation is really the selection sort... if it is, why is it so fast

Comment: Why are the other sorts so slow? Surely sorting a 10,000 element array shouldn't take seconds.

Comment: AskAnyway, that's a good point... I added the bubble sort implementation for reference. probably my other implementation is wrong instead.

Comment: @HaoLuo I find it very hard to believe that takes 2.2 seconds, please post `this.swap`

Comment: @Connor Thanks. I found why it was taking so long, I was doing some stupid logging check in the swap.. after I deleted the logging, it's all definitely faster, but Selection Sort is still much faster. See updated durations

Comment: See: http://jsperf.com/sorts-by-hao-luo

Comment: Selection sort is 2x faster than Bubble sort, because it makes 10 000 less writes into array. Isn't it obvious? Each primitive action is going to take some time.

Comment: Just two comments: The swap function can be implemented with just three assignments, not four. Also, the test `if (min !== target)` is not a good idea: For the few cases it will save some time in the swap, all other cases will loose time in the test.

Answer (score 2):

First let me point out two flaws:

- The code for your selection sort is faulty. The inner loop needs to be

  ```
  for (var j = target + 1; j < this.length; j++) {
  ```

  otherwise the last element is never selected.
- Your jsperf tests sort, as you say, the "*same randomly generated array*" every time. That means that the successive runs in each test loop will try to sort an already sorted array, which would favour algorithms like bubblesort that have a linear best-case performance.

  Luckily, your test array is so freakishly large that jsperf runs only a single iteration of its test loop at once, calling the setup code that initialises the array before every run. This would haunt you for smaller arrays, though. You need to shuffle the array inside the "timed code" itself.

---

> Why is Selection Sort faster? My only guess is that Javascript is really fast at array traversal but slow at value mutation.

Yes. Writes are always slower than reads, and have negative effects on cached values as well.

> SelectionSort uses the least in value mutation

Yes, and that is quite significant. Both selection and bubble sort do have an `O(n²)` runtime, which means that both execute about 100000000 loop condition checks, index increments, and comparisons of two array elements.

However, while selection sort does only `O(n)` swaps, bubble sort does `O(n²)` of them. That means not only mutating the array, but also the overhead of a method call. And that much much more often than the selection sort does it. Here are some [example logs](http://jsperf.com/sorts-by-hao-luo/2):

```
> swaps in .selectionSort() of 10000 element arrays
9989
9986
9992
9990
9987
9995
9989
9990
9988
9991
> swaps in .bubbleSort() of 10000 element arrays
24994720
25246566
24759007
24912175
24937357
25078458
24918266
24789670
25209063
24894328
```

Ooops.

Comment: Thanks for the awesome answer! I saw the error in my code last night and fixed it :)